# Are there any ways to declare AMP on <head> besides the rel = "amphtml" link on Discourse

Tags: discourse

Problem: I use **Discourse** as a **blog**. I built an AMP version but could not **declare AMP** in the head.

- Theme editor Only one fixed link can be inserted before
- Or use javascript to add  after the page is loaded, but Google Bot doesn't crawl it.

**So?**
Are there any other declarations? For example sitemap or structured-data

My question on Discourse : https://meta.discourse.org/t/add-dynamic-content-to-head-any-tips/143815